# Vue.js Build not working with npm run build

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get **vue.js** source code for production.
I used  this command `npm run build`. I got a `dist` folder with `index.html` and a folder named `static` with all `css` and `js`.

When I tried running the `index.html` in localhost, **ie**, **xampp server** I got a blank page .

Is it possible with **vue.js** to run in **xampp**.

Comment: the blank page could mean that there is some js error, could you open browser dev tools js console and see what is there?

Comment: Did you use `vue-cli`?

Answer (score 11):

First create **vue.config.js** file in project root directory and define base url in it using below code

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : '/'
}
```

If you use Vue CLI 3.3 or higher, use

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
      '/production-sub-path/' :
      '/'
}
```

Replace **production-sub-path** with your folder name ... eg. http://www.example.com/production-sub-path/ ... and run below command to build the project

```
npm run build
```

After finishing the build ... Copy/Upload all files in **dist** folder to your /production-sub-path/ folder... That's it

For more info checkout the official documentation
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines

Comment: for those getting the following error: `Invalid options in vue.config.js: "baseUrl" is not allowed` I was able to fix it by changing `baseUrl` to `publicPath` instead

Comment: If using Vue CLI > 3.3 know that baseUrl is deprecated and [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) should be used

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue before as well. I solved it by making a change to the index.js file in the config folder. Under build, I changed:

```
assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

to

```
assetsPublicPath: '',
```

and tried npm run build again. I checked the dist file and opened the index.html and it worked, no blank page.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and I solved the problem by deleting the **"/"** from the dist/index.html file. I had something like this:

```
<script src=/js/app.632f4e30.js></script>
```

And I change it to:

```
<script src=js/app.632f4e30.js></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I created vue.config.js next to the file package.json

With the following content:

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: ''
}
```

And run
`npm run build`

It solved my problem

The following links helped me

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/310

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js

Comment: Take into account this is correct for Vue CLI > 3.3, if not you should use baseUrl instead

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you do a production build the paths that get set in the index.html file prepend a slash in front of it meaning that it will look for the file in the base domain. So im guessing your just trying to open the file in the browser by double clicking the index.html file and having it open in the browser.

Something like
`file:///Users/brianvoelker/Desktop/websites/vue-build/docs/index.html`
So in that example it is trying to look for files in `file:///` and of course the dont exist.

So you can do either two things open the index.html file and remove the slash at the beginning or just know when you deploy that it will work because the files lookup are relative to the base domain.

P.S. If your looking for a cli build tool check out [Vue-build.com](http://vue-build.com)

Comment: actually, double-clicking the file opens the file correctly, problem is the build was not successful and the index is blank

Answer (score 1):

Open vue.config.js you see the following code.

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

update code to this

```
 const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath:''
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js is a browser side app framework. The server side technology does not matter, unless you are attempting to do server side rendering.

`npm run build` works perfectly alright, and it creates a minified set of files for `manifest.#.js`, `vendor.#.js` and `app.#.js`

Open the network tab in developer tools of Google Chrome to see what files are getting loaded. If any of the js files are not getting loaded, it is a path configuration that you need to do, so that your server serves the right files.

You may have to tweak the `index.html` file a bit so that it fully meets your requirements, and move the `js` files from `dist/static` folder to your preferred location. The url path does not matter, as long as the app files are served in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and the above info helped me.  However, I found that if you edit the index.js file in the config folder for the VueJS CLI webpack tooling and edit the 'assetsPublicPath:' variable to './' from the default '/' then future builds will find the correct references to the css and js files in the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding this code  under root directory,

```
module.exports = {
     publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
     ? './'
     : '/'
}
```

or you can remove first '/' from index.html file that has been created  under dist. 
example href=/js/chunk-vendors.7a32d01e.js to href=js/chunk-vendors.7a32d01e.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation with a different issue, I used the `vuejs-webpack-project` project and tried running the output files under an IIS server.

This code in `index.html` didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>vuejs-webpack-project</title>
  <link href=/static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=app />
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js />
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js />
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js />
</body>
</html>
```

This code worked(needed to change the closing tags of the script elemet):

```
<body>
    <div id=app />
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js ></script>
</body>
```